# Data annotations not displaying error message in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a simple cshtml page in MVC 4 as following:

```
@model  MvcApplication2.ViewModels.UserViewModel
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
              @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "User", FormMethod.Post))
              {
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ime)
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
                <br />
                <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Add user" />
              }
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my UserViewModel class:

```
   public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
        public string FirstName;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
        public string LastName;        
    }
```

And this is the action "add" in the controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(User s)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Connection.dm.User.Add(s);
                Connection.dm.SaveChanges();
            }
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The issue here is that I get no error messages at all if the user hasn't entered something in the 2 textbox fields... What could it be?

Comment: What does happen when there is nothing in the textbox fields? Does it save? where does it redirect you to?

Comment: It doesn't saves anything to the DB... The ModelState.IsValid is set to false therefore it just redirects the user to the action, which is Index, and that just basically refreshes the website...

Comment: Okay I fixed the issue. The issue was that I needed to do the following: return View("AddUser"); instead of RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: okay, I was just about to post `return View(s)`.. you also might want to use try.. catch.. blocks just for more exception handling.. ill post something in the answer section just for another route you could take

Comment: Okay sure, that would be quite nice. By the way. What is the best way to implement ViewModels? Should I put all my ViewModels into one class, or should every ViewModel have its own class? What is the best practice to do that? :)

Comment: I would suggest every ViewModel have its own class.. with my experience using MVC i put all of my viewmodels into their own classes.. it creates seperation and avoids confusion.. i would just create a folder called "ViewModels" and just put them all in there for more organization

Comment: Okay thanks alot!! By the way, should data annotations be used with Entity classes or the ones  that are created for a view model?? Like, I use data annotations on Entity classes, and then just create an property of that entity class inside viewmodel ?? Or Its a better practice to create the each property manually inside viewmodel and "map" it with data annotations?

Comment: Use data annotations with your view model.  Idk if you use entity framework, but if you put data annotations in your entity classes.. then go back to your database and make a change.. then update your model (entity class) from the database.. the data annotations will be erased.. but they will always be there in your view model even after updates from the database

Comment: Yes I'm using entity framework. Right, good point, thanks for pointing that out to me! :-)

Comment: you're welcome. Happy coding

Comment: You should not even be hitting the POST method when you click the submit button unless you have disabled client side validation. Add `jquery-{version}.js` before the other 2 validation scripts (currently client side validation will not work because you have omitted jquery

Answer (score 1):

in reference to using try.. catch.. blocks, you could do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(User s)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try{
                Connection.dm.User.Add(s);
                Connection.dm.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(NullReferenceException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Ime", "Please enter something"); // for the first name validation
                return View(s);
        }
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

or you could use some conditional logic like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(User s)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Ime)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Ime", "Please enter something");
                return View(s);
            }
            else
            {
            Connection.dm.User.Add(s);
            Connection.dm.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```